# Swift Concurrency - Is there a downside to tagging ALL UI accessing classes and structs with @MainActor?

Tags: swift

This is a question regarding overall architecture for a UIKit iOS app following Swift's new structured concurrency model introduced in Swift 5.5.

I've been transitioning my app that uses MVVM UIKit architecture to Swift's new concurrency model (i.e. using async/await, Task{}, etc).

Instead of *tagging individual methods* with @MainActor, I am wondering **if there are any performance downsides or other risks** associated with tagging all of my View Controller classes and View Model structs with @MainActor?

This seems to me to be both the safest and most simple option to avoid an unexpected access to the UI off the main thread.

Comment: No real downside. Obviously, just be careful (like always) to move anything slow and synchronous off the main actor. FWIW, `UIViewController` is already marked as `@MainActor` already.

Comment: Probably the "downside" is, that actors makes the otherwise hidden issues _explicit_: an actor wants to be called from an async context, so that it is _possible_  for the compiler and runtime to switch to the actor's execution context IFF necessary. So, you have to provide this async context. Formerly, the code may not know about race conditions, or made the _implicit_ assumption that everything is running on the main thread. Of course, that was a very brittle assumption. ;)